# How to plot this equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, equation

alright well I have the follow function

```
y=sin(x)^2 + [(10+2x+x^2) / (5+2x^2)]
```

i need to plot it on the interval y = -2 to y = 2 so how would I set that up?

I did this in matlab

```
   >>  y = sin(x).^2 + (10 + 2*x + x.^2)/(5+2*x.^2)
   >>  x = -2:0.01:2;
```

is that a correct setup? Or have I done something wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare a variable before you use it. In this case, x doesn't depend on y, so declare it first. In addition, there is a `./` operator missing.

```
x = -2:0.01:2;
y=sin(x).^2 + (10+2*x+x.^2) ./ (5+2*x.^2);
plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = @(x) sin(x)^2 + [(10+2*x+x^2) / (5+2*x^2)];
ezplot(f)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.